# ASP.NET MVC 4 using Entity Framework : how to save images in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**I am beginner** to ASP.NET MVC 4 ... I want to upload images from my form and save them into the SQL database by using Entity Framework. I have searched a lot but couldn't succeed yet,,

Comment: This will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185848/how-to-save-an-image-to-database-using-mvc-4
[Uplopad and Fetch image in mvc][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185848/how-to-save-an-image-to-database-using-mvc-4

Comment: Please include some code to show us what you've tried.

Comment: At the risk of starting a flame war, unless you have a very specific business case that requires images actually be stored in the database, refrain from doing so. Pulling an image from a database for display on the web requires spinning up the entire ASP.NET framework just to serve the image, where as a static reference to an image allows IIS to serve it directly. Also, you'll have zero ability to optimize resource handling through things like CDNs, etc.

Answer (score 3):

First Convert image into bytes and then assign generated bytes of the property of you model.

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

and then

```
YourModel obj = new YourModel()
obj.Image = imageToByteArray(image);
yourDbContext.YourModels.Add(obj);
yourDbContext.Savechanges()
```

Edited: From Byte[] to image

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     Image returnImage = null;
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
     {
         returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     }
     return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: How to retrieve image after saving this?

Comment: Convert back the bytes to Image. I have edited the answer accordingly.