# Object Refernce is not set to instance of an object -mvc4

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller in which I have Create method .My aim is to upload picture along with name and service involved for a particular person.My code is perfectly good.But I'm hitting the error 'Object reference  not set to the instance of an object' at the line 'if (leader.File.ContentLength > (2 * 1024 * 1024))' in controller.The code is perfectly good.Please let me know where I'm doing mistake

I have model class like this:

```
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int ID { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage="The Name is required")] 
   [MaxLength(20,ErrorMessage="The Maximum characters allowed is 20")]
   [MinLength(4,ErrorMessage="The Minimum charcaters allowed is 4")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage="Picture is required")]
   public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

   public int ImageSize { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

   public int MinistryID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("MinistryID")]
   public virtual Ministry Ministry { get; set; }
```

I have Controller class with create method  like this:

```
   public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Leader leader)
        {
            if (leader.File.ContentLength > (2 * 1024 * 1024))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "File size must be
             less than 2 MB");
                return View();
            }
            if (!(leader.File.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || 
           leader.File.ContentType == "image/gif"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "File type allowed :
              jpeg and gif");
                return View();
            }

            leader.ImageSize = leader.File.ContentLength;

            byte[] data = new byte[leader.File.ContentLength];
            leader.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0,
            leader.File.ContentLength);

            leader.Picture = data;
           if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Leaders.Add(leader);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View(leader);

        }
        }
```

The View of the Create method is :

```
     @model ChurchWebsite.Models.Leader

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Leader</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Picture)
        </div>
         <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload","Image", FormMethod.Post,new{enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
            {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model=> Model.File, new{type="file",enctype="multipart/form-data"})
            @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
           </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinistryID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MinistryID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinistryID)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: _My code is perfectly good_ No it not! Because `File` is `null` (you don't have a form control for uploading a file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: And the model in the view is typeof `Ministry` but the POST method you have shown bind to typeof `Leader` You have not even shown the right code!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have Html.BeginForm at the beginning of view .Should I include it again near the Upload of file

Comment: @sujayraj No. See: [Is it valid to have a html form inside another html form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form)

Comment: You cannot have nested forms. Remove the inner form. Add `new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }` to the outer form and remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the file input (and don't use capital `M` Model in expressions).

Comment: @StephenMuecke nailed it. As an aside, note that one solid troubleshooting method is to strip your MVC flow down to a simple, working process, [like the one shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19186560/772086), and then iteratively build it out to match your intended model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested forms which is invalid html and when you click the submit button in the inner form, it will post the outer form which does not have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute and as a consequence, the file is not sent and in the controller, `leader.File` is null and accessing its `ContentLength` property throws the exception. You need to remove the inner nested form element and add the `enctype` attribute to the outer form.

Your view should be (irrelevant html removed)

```
@model ChurchWebsite.Models.Leader
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", YourControllerName, FormMethod.Post, new{ enctype="multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    ....
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    ....
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new{ type="file" }) // remove the inva;id enctype attribute
    @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
    ....
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinistryID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MinistryID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinistryID)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Comment: Sorry Stephen, I tried your code.I'm not getting any error.But I see that the data is not stored in the database

Comment: Has the exception gone?

Comment: Yep..It's gone..@Stephen

Comment: Then you question has been answered :). If you have another problem then ask a new question.

Comment: It's working when I removed the code 'if(ModelState.IsValid)' in the Action Method.Thanks a ton

Comment: That's because you have a `[Required]` attribute on the `Picture` so when you submit the form, the `DefaultModelBinder` added a `ModelState` error because `Picture` was null. You should remove it so you can still test if its valid.