# Save Multiple Images to Database using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My code only saves first input image. I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19186560/5460277) to see how I can handle with multiple images. If I change `HttpPostedFileBase` to `HttpPostedFileBase[]`, I cannot use `InputStream` and `ContentLength` for `HttpPostedFileBase image`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Color,CategoryId,GenderId,Image")] Product product, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            byte[] imagee = null;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                image = Request.Files[0];
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream))
                {
                    imagee = br.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
                }
            }
            product.Image = imagee;
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I show the only one image like this:

```
<img class="img-rounded img-responsive" src="data:image/jpg;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image)" width="250" height="400" />
```

How can I store multiple images and also show them?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use _InputStream and ContentLength_? And why are you using `Request.Files[0]` - your method already has a parameter for the files. If its `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> image`, then you just loop through the files - `foreach(HtttpPostedFileBase file in image) { ....`

Comment: by mean that, it shows `definition for 'InputStream' and no extension method 'InputStream' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpPostedFileBase[]' could be found` and same error for `ContentLength`. Our professor shared this code but I want to extend the code as storing multiple images. According to your comment, do I just use `foreach` to get every input?

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase[]` is a collection - you need to loop though the collection to get each file in it. And of course your `product.Image` wont work since that only holds one image. You need a second database table to store the images (with a FK to the Product ID)

Comment: So new model will have Id primary key, ProductId foreign key, and Image in byte[]. When I select multiple images, the program will store them by using new created model and I will get the images from that new created model to show them. Am I right or can you show one sample?

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen mentioned in the comment, your current entity class definitions is for storing a single image against the product (one to one). If you prefer to have multiple images for an image, you should consider creating another table for images and have a one to many connections between them.

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id { set; get;}
  public string Name { set; get;}
  public string Color { set; get;}
  // Add other properties needed as well

  public ICollection<Image> Images { set; get;}
}
public class Image
{
  public int Id { set; get;}
  public byte[] ImageData { set; get;}
  public int ProductId { set; get;}
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Color,CategoryId,GenderId")]
                          Product product, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.Products.Add(product);

         if (images!=null)
         {
            var imageList= new List<Image>();
            foreach(var image in images)
            {
               using (var br = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream))
               {
                 var data = br.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
                 var img=new Image { ProductId=product.Id };
                 img.ImageData = data;
                 imageList.Add(img);
               }
            }
            product.Images = imageList;
         }
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(product);
}
```